# Does Azure Durable Function Eternal Orchestrations restart immediately after ContinueAsNew?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I read about Eternal Orchestration [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-eternal-orchestrations?tabs=csharp) that we can get orchestrator to run "infinitely" by calling ContinueAsNew which will reset its state.

Does the orchestrator rerun immediately? or only after finish executing all of the statements in the function (i.e. based on the code below, will "End of function" be log out when the **if condition** is met or does it breaks out of the function and re-execute the orchestrator?)?

```
[FunctionName("Periodic_Cleanup_Loop")]
public static async Task Run(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
{
    await context.CallActivityAsync("DoCleanup", null);

    // sleep for one hour between cleanups
    DateTime nextCleanup = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddHours(1);
    await context.CreateTimer(nextCleanup, CancellationToken.None);

    if (condition)
       context.ContinueAsNew(null);

    log.logInformation("End of the function");
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The execution will always complete until the end of the function or until running into some error. This means that you would see the "End of the function" be logged. If you were to have many ContinueAsNew only the last executed will run when the function terminates. In practice, you may do anything after you have used ContinueAsNew

e.g.

```cs
        [FunctionName("Orch")]
        public static async Task Orchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger log)
        {
            int input = context.GetInput<int>();

            await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Acti", input.ToString());

            context.ContinueAsNew(input + 1);

            context.ContinueAsNew(input + 2);

            await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Acti", input.ToString() + " : second");

            log.LogInformation("End of the function");
        }

        [FunctionName("Acti")]
        public static async Task Activity(
        [ActivityTrigger] IDurableActivityContext inputs, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation(inputs.GetInput<string>());
        }
```

This would log.

```
0
0 : second
End of the function
2
2 : second
End of the function
4
4 : second
End of the function
...
```

What context.ContinueAsNew really does is just tell the orchestration context to start a new orchestrator with the same InstanceId when the function terminates. Using ContinueAsNew somewhere in the code would be "almost" the same as putting `context.StartAsNew("Orch", /*random instanceId*/, input)` at the absolute end of the function. The only difference is that when the function terminates StartAsNew would start creating a new execution history in TableStorage but ContinueAsNew would reuse the same history which may reduce some troubleshooting options but will save storage.

Comment: Thank you @Bjorne. May I clarify, having `context.ContinueAsNew(input + 2);` followed by `context.ContinueAsNew(input + 1);`, overrides the input value, thats why the sequence is 0, 2, 4, 6, ... instead of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4? As such, essentially regardless on the number of continueAsNew, in the orchestrator, only the last one is taken into account (since it overrides the previous ones)?

Comment: Yes that is correct. All that continue as new really does is set some internal variable to the next input ( can be overritten) and then uses that variable to start again after fubction finishes

Comment: The most important thing with `ContinueAsNew` is that it completely clears the execution history of the orchestration before restarting the orchestration. That is also the main reason for using it.